# Show that $(X_{n})_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}$ is stationary

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stationarity

I'm trying to understand and teach myself stochastic processes. I'm very sorry in advance if I'm asking a dumb question. So, I came across an exercise in which the following is stated.
For every $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ let $(X_{n}^{k})_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}$ denote a stationary process with state space $S=\mathbb{R}$. Assume that $(X_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ is an stochastic process with state space $S=\mathbb{R}$ such that $X_{n}^{k} \to X$ for $k\to\infty$ in probability for each $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.
Show that $(X_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ is stationary.
What I've so far learned is that a stochastic process $(X_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ is stationary if
$$(X_{0},\ldots,X_{n})\overset{\text{d}}{=}(X_{k},...,X_{k+n}) \qquad \text{for every} \enspace n\in\mathbb{N}_{0} \enspace \text{and} \enspace k\in\mathbb{Z}.$$
I havn't been able to find an useful answer on here to point me in the right direction. So, my question is how do I actually show that $(X_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ is stationary. Can somebody point me to a post I might have over seen or explain me in an intuitive way on how to show this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to show that elementwise convergence in probability implies $\text{plim}_{k \rightarrow \infty} (X_n^k) = (X_n)$ (i.e., convergence of the sequence).  Thus, your conjecture effectively stipulates that the [probability-limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Convergence_in_probability) of a sequence of strongly stationary sequences is also a strongly stationary sequence.  Since convergence in probability implies convergence in distribution, for all $\ell \in \mathbb{Z}$ you have:

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(X_1 \leqslant x_1,...,X_n \leqslant x_n)
&= \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{P}(X_1^k \leqslant x_1,...,X_n^k \leqslant x_n) \\[6pt]
&= \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{P}(X_{\ell+1}^k \leqslant x_1,...,X_{\ell+n}^k \leqslant x_n) \\[6pt]
&= \mathbb{P}(X_{\ell+1} \leqslant x_1,...,X_{\ell+n} \leqslant x_n), \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

which demonstrates that the sequence $(X_n)$ is strongly stationary.

Comment: Ah, so pointwise convergence implies convergence in probability, right? Except from that it makes a lot more sense to be now. I think it was the first part that wasn't so obvious for me. Thank you for your explanation.

Comment: Pointwise convergence and convergence in probability are two different concepts that do not relate via simple implication.  "Pointwise" refers to the fact that there is convergence at individual points over a set, whereas convergence "in probability" is a type of convergence relating to a probability measure.

Comment: I think the elementwise convergence you mentioned in your answer threw me off. If you didn't mean pointwise convergence with that can you explain it?

Comment: Your question says that $\text{plim}_{k \rightarrow \infty} X_n^k = X_n$ for each $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, which is "elementwise" convergence (i.e., convergence over each element $n$).

Comment: Oh, I see that now. Thank you for your explanation it helped a lot